# Facebook Activity Feed in Mobile Game (iOS and Android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I'm wondering how to feed an Game Activity on facebook from my mobile application(android game).

I know hot to make a post in the wall in facebook but I want directly to post in GameActivity not on the wall.
For example here ([Game Activity Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/apps/feed)) are apps wich one do that.
Have anyone tried to integrate your mobile application with this activity ?

Okey, I have found Graph API and now I'm wondering if i cand feed from graph not from dialog.
for example i got editor 
[Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=100000681338439?fields=id,name)
BUT... I have no idea how to use it ;/
The problem is in that, how to feed (post) from application to facebook so that the entry is visible in 'Game Feed' on Facebook

I'm using comend:

`100000291400297/feed?link=http://example.com/embed/&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN& app_id=503449429707505 &type=game&url=http://example.com/embed/& title=Tutul Aplikacji& description=opis aplikacji`

and it's not working cus the result is:

`Me shared a link via Device.`

I want to make somethink like:

`Me scored some points in game SomeGame.`

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You might want to check this [How-to article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-gaming/).

Comment: Hey, thx for swear but it's not helping me. I already tried to do this ;/

Comment: Or rather, you might be looking for [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/scores/)

Comment: I think the orginal proposition is what I need but I can't apply it...
there is no clear information for me... or I dont understand. When I got my own story line and my own Objects how i use it ?

Comment: Just to be clear, is this, the Scores API, what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not a looking for an API, i got my own API(in my aps on facebook) wich one i want to test Graph (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

now I want make my apk will feed Games in 
(https://www.facebook.com/apps/feed)
and posting on the walls and do somethink like that
(https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/851564_161673230668352_1774117249_n.png)